# check out page sub total text issue in zen-cart

Tags: php, e-commerce, zen-cart

I'm working in zen-cart and my issue is, in check out page there comes a section called shopping cart contents which displays the items name and content and total amount.

Later there come the sub-total section, parcel, tax and total section

I'm not sure from where these values come from and how can I edit or configure them.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Are you wondering about the *labels* for subtotal, tax, etc. or the *values*?

The labels are controlled by files in includes/languages/english/modules/order_total.
For instance, the label "Sub-Total" is in ot_subtotal.php in that directory.

You can change these by creating a directory with the name of your template in 
includes/languages/english/modules/order_total, copying the relevant files in, and editing them there.

The values are computed by files in includes/modules/order_total.  But the values these files return are set according to flags and values you set in your admin panel, such as tax rate and so forth.

Comment: Thats one of the issue Scott, my major issue is, in live site the sub-total labels and the figures I get is 
Sub-Total: $254.10
Total Shipping Charges (18.38 lbs total weight): $16.47
Sub-Total before taxes: $270.57
HILLSBOROUGH County Tax (1%): $2.71
FL State Tax (6%): $16.23
Total Sales Tax (after discount if any): $18.94
Total: $289.51

Comment: This looks fine to me.  What's the problem?

Comment: See Scott in dev site there are missing fields like Sub-Total before taxes: $270.57, HILLSBOROUGH County Tax (1%): $2.71, FL State Tax (6%): $16.23 and Total Sales Tax (after discount if any): $18.94 from live site I'm not sure from where they got it from.

Comment: Go to admin->locations/taxes->tax rates on both sites and compare.

Comment: I did that Scott both sites have no data to compare.